# How to remove homegroup icon from Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, homegroup

I'd like to remove "Homegroup" from the left side of my Windows Explorer in Windows 7/8.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To remove Homegroup (and stop Homegroup networking functionality):

Go to Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> HomeGroup, and click on "Leave the homegroup" link and confirm to unjoin from any existing home group.
Note: If the home group are shared and hosted from the PC, all HomeGroup connections will be disconnected.

In the future, if you want to use Homegroup networking you can create a homegroup using this same dialog.

Go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools, and double click on Services. Alternatively, type `services.msc` in Start Search.

For each of the following two services:

- HomeGroup Listener
- HomeGroup Provider

Do the following:

Stop the service, and then double click on the service to open Properties dialog, and set its Startup type to "Disabled". Click OK when done.  In order to reinstate Homegroup functionality in the future, you will want to set the Startup type back to Manual.

The HomeGroup icon and group will no longer be shown in the navigation pane of Windows Explorer in Windows 7.  Note that this does not interrupt "traditional" windows networking functionality (e.g., Map Network Drive).

more useful links:

- [Remove Favorites, Libraries, and Homegroup from Navigation Pane](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/ac419c2b-4a38-44f0-b1f0-b0ed9fdcfdeb)
- [Disable and Turn Off HomeGroup Services to Hide or Remove Home Group from Windows 7 Explorer](http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-and-turn-off-homegroup-services-to-hide-or-remove-home-group-from-windows-7-explorer/)

Comment: Thanks, saw a lot of registry based things but simply leaving the homegroup has removed the icon.

Comment: For a fresh installation, the section about services.msc is all you need to do.  This works on Windows 10 as well, which ships with HomeGroup pre-installed and running and pinned to the explorer window.

Answer (score 3):

To remove just the icon in Windows Explorer, edit the following Registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{B4FB3F98-C1EA-428d-A78A-D1F5659CBA93}\ShellFolder\Attributes
```

To disable the *Homegroup* icon use the value `b094010c`; to re-enable it again use `b084010c`.

If you get a *permission denied* error, change the permissions on the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{B4FB3F98-C1EA-428d-A78A-D1F5659CBA93}\ShellFolder` key so that you have *full control*.

Comment: On Windows 10 I had to follow [these](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-get-rid-of-skydrive-in-windows-8-1-explorer-1447031829) directions in order to change the owner before I could change the permissions (substitute the key in this answer though). Then I had to restart Explorer (using Task Manager, or just sign out and back in) before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First, leave any homegroup network as follows:

start > control panel > network and internet > home group. Then click on *Leave homegroup link*. Click finish when done.

Now, to get rid of the icon from the explorer

start > control panel > system and security > administrative tools > services

now you need to deal with two services.
**Homegroup Listener**
**Homegroup Provider**
For both, stop the service. Double click to open its PROPERTIES. Set its STARTUP TYPE to disabled.
Done

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the Homegroup Icon in the Explorer:

The Peer Networking services and Homegroup Services MUST be started.

Otherwise, you will get an error message when attempting to "Leave the Homegroup".

Comment: As written, your answer provides very little useful information. Can you expand it on a bit?